# Save base64 to image / video on Digital Ocean spaces

Tags: php, ionic-framework, digital-ocean

I am using Digital Ocean spaces. I found [Spaces-API](https://github.com/SociallyDev/Spaces-API/) on GitHub. Now it is giving the option to upload file using below code, and I am able to upload image.

Requirement: From client clide, I will be passing base64 using Ionic. I am wondering how can I pass and save it as a JPEG.

```
<?php
require_once("spaces.php");
$my_space = Spaces("M6Z255BGH6RROB5EUB3O", "vXF4XhpZ7/OyBINQaDNXex4DLuR/cBPDjfARhoSLB2A")->space("pbro", "fra1");

//Upload some text.
$my_space->upload("Super cool content", "example1.txt");

//Upload some image.
$my_space->uploadFile("img.png", "img_1.png");

//Uploaded!
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1:

Use the `upload` method and pass image content as text, but decode it first:

```
$my_space->upload(base64_decode($encodedImage), 'img.jpg')
```

*This won't work because Spaces treats files uploaded this way as text files and returns them with `application/octet-stream` header.*

## Option 2:

Dump decoded content to temp file first, so You can check if the image is valid and process it before pushing to Spaces eg.:

```
$filepath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'spacesupload');
file_put_contents($filepath, base64_decode($encodedImage));

// process file here

$my_space->uploadFile($filepath, "img_1.png");

// remove uploaded file from server
unlink($filepath);
```

**Note**

It is possible that instead of file contents, data passed from frontend to backend is in format `data:image/gif;base64,[encoded string]`. In that case You'd need to get the encoded string only to push to Spaces eg.:

```
$encodedString = explode('base64,', 'data:image/gif;base64,[encoded string]', 2);
if (count($encodedString) !== 2) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid encoded image string');
}

$encodedImage = $encodedString[1];

// proceed with upload
// ...
```

Comment: Image uploaded with problem - when i open image from direct link it downloads instead of opening, reason i found - `Content-Type application/octet-stream` , i think it should be `Content-Type image/png` or `Content-Type image/jpg` , how do i manage this ?

Comment: Please note: I am using option 1

Comment: I don't know spaces this much, sorry. But I suspect Ionic might be sending not just encoded image content but mime type as well. The format is then `data:image/gif;base64,[encoded string]`. In that case You'd need to get the encoded string only to push to Spaces

Comment: Current for testing i am just hard coding in `PHP` directly , not using Ionic at the moment, i AM NOT ADDING `data:image/gif;base64,` , here is what i am doing `$my_space->upload(base64_decode("iVBORw0......`  but even after adding this is not working

Comment: It is possible that Spaces doesn't allow You to upload image as string. Try option 2. If it works, I'll update my answer

Comment: Option 2 looks non suitable to me because my php server is different and files are being hosted on DO spaces , if i choose option 2, it will means that 1st it will upload to php server and then to DO spaces...am i right ?

Comment: In both cases, image is already available on server - just in memory. What option 2 does is storing the image in temp dir to upload it. Once the file is uploaded to Spaces, You can safely delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send base64ecoded file in the parameter and it's extension so that you can easily write down that file to it's orignal extension, and you can use a common function like this

```
function createImageFromBase64($data,$folder,$file) {

   if (!file_exists($folder)) {
      mkdir($folder, 0755, true);
   }

   list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
   list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
   //Note you only need this if you're sending base64 along with it's native 
   //delimeters otherwise you can skip above two lines.
   $data               = base64_decode($data);

   file_put_contents($folder.'/'.$file, $data); }
```